# Streaming audio with Pygame

Tags: python, rest, stream, pygame

I'm creating an application that will stream audio to a Raspberry Pi from a server on the local network using a Python script. I'd like to play the files with pygame (preferrably) but not store them locally. The files will be accessible through a REST API.
Is it possible to use pygame.mixer.music or something similar? From the [docs](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.load) on pygame.mixer.music:

> The difference between the music playback and regular Sound playback is that the music is streamed, and never actually loaded all at once.

Much like [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33320218/get-an-audio-file-with-http-get-and-then-play-it-in-python-3-tts-in-python-3), but with pygame.

Comment: I have half-prepared an answer, but have hit a snag myself - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58702442/wrap-an-io-bufferediobase-such-that-it-becomes-seek-able

Comment: Thanks @Kingsley, I guess I can use some of your code. My application is pretty simple, just lacks the possibility of streaming.